# Intersection of tetrahedra

Tags: python, geometry, linear-algebra, linear-programming

I hope to be as clear as possible.
I'm trying to implement a function that, given two tetrahedra, checks if they intersect with each other.
I am working with python and the only library I am using is NumPy.
To describe a tetrahedron I use its 4 vertices which are each described by coordinates [x, y, z].

```
vertex = [x, y, z]

tetrahedra = [vertex 1,vertex 2,vertex 3,vertex 4]
```

This is the reasoning I want to use:

- A tetrahedron is nothing more than a region defined by inequalities.
- These inequalities are described by the planes containing one face of the tetrahedron.
- So given the inequalities of the two tetrahedra, and putting them in a system, if this system admits a
  solution then there is an intersection.

This is my function:

```
def IsInterpenetrated(self, tetrahedra):
    A= []
    B= []
    sol= 0
    for tr in [self, tetrahedra]:
        print("Plane of tetrahedra")
        vertexList = tr.vertices
        i=0
        while i<4:
            if handedness(vertexList)>0:
                n= numpy.cross(vertexList[1].coords - vertexList[0].coords, vertexList[2].coords - vertexList[0].coords)
            else:
                n= numpy.cross(vertexList[2].coords - vertexList[0].coords, vertexList[1].coords - vertexList[0].coords)
            
            p0= vertexList[0].coords
            d= -(n[0]*p0[0] + n[1]*p0[1] + n[2]*p0[2])
            
            print("normal: ", n , end="      ")
            print("termine noto: ",(d))

            if len(A) > 3:
                j=0
                while j<=3:
                    if numpy.all(-n == A[j]) and -d == B[j]:
                        sol = 1
                    j= j+1

            A.append(n)
            B.append(d)

            p0= vertexList[0]
            vertexList[0] = vertexList[1]
            vertexList[1] = vertexList[2]
            vertexList[2] = vertexList[3]
            vertexList[3] = p0

            i=i+1

    A= numpy.array(A)
    B= numpy.array(B)
    print("\n")

    print("Disequazioni:\n")
    i=0
    for n in A:
        print("({0})x + ({1})y + ({2})z + ({3}) > 0".format(n[0],n[1],n[2],B[i]))
        i=i+1
    print("\n")

    x = cvxpy.Variable(3)
    prob = cvxpy.Problem(cvxpy.Minimize(0),[A @ x + B >= 0])
    prob.solve()
    if prob.value == 0 and sol != 1:
        return 1
    return 0
```

In this case I have solved the system of inequalities using cvxpy and I have verified the particular case in which the two tetrahedra have a common face.
I was wondering if you think the following reasoning is correct to avoid working with systems of inequalities.
Each plane that identifies the face of the tetrahedron belongs to the family of bundles of parallel planes which are described in the following way; ax + by + cz + k = 0 where k is the term that indicates the exact position of the plane on space. Then I can describe the tetrahedron in the following way:

```
System:
a'x + b'y + c'z = k '
a "x + b" y + c "z = k"
a '"x + b'" y + c '"z = k'"
a "" x + b "" y + c "" z = k ""
```

with k > d where d is the known term of the plane that identifies the face.
Thanks to the [Rouché-Capelli theorem](https://www.youmath.it/lezioni/algebra-lineare/matrici-e-vettori/757-rouche-capelli-per-sistemi-lineari.html)  I know that this system admits solution if Rg (A) = Rg (A | B) where Rg stands for [rank](https://www.youmath.it/lezioni/algebra-lineare/matrici-e-vettori/769-rango-di-una-matrice.html). To ensure that this equality is respected then Det (A | B) = 0 where Det stands for [determinant](https://www.youmath.it/lezioni/algebra-lineare/matrici-e-vettori/767-calcolo-del-determinante.html). Since B in my case consists of variables:

```
(k ', k ", k"', ......, kᵐ)
```

then to make Det (A | B) = 0 I have to solve the equation that is created by this calculation. Having carried out this reasoning for both tetrahedra, I find myself with two equations with 3 unknowns. One for each tetrahedron. By putting these two equations into a system I have to see for which values of k it admits solutions. If there are values of k for which the system is respected then I have intersection, otherwise no.
I don't know how feasible it is but I preferred to share my idea, in order to discuss it together.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi again! Better ask this edited version `I apparently solved the problem of intersections between tetrahedra using cvxpy, but I was wondering if there was a similar reasoning without using systems of inequalities.` as a separate question and link relevant parts to this question. Since this question already has an accepted answer, many people may not look at it.

Comment: OK perfect! Thanks so much for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not formulate a convex optimization problem, or precisely a feasibility problem using the plane inequalities that you have? Let's say, the two tetrahedra can be represented as `A1.X + d1 <= 0` and `A2.X + d2 <= 0` where the 4 rows of `A1` and `A2` store the `a, b, c` of four planes corresponding to the two tetrahedra in `ax + by + cz + d <= 0`, and column vectors `d1` and `d2` store the constants ie `d`. And also note that `A1.X` is matrix multiplication.

Represent `(x, y, z)` as the vector `X`.

Now basically you want to solve a feasibility problem for `X` like this:

```
minimize 0
subject to A1.X + d1 <= 0
           A2.X + d2 <= 0
```

Note that if the solver returns `inf`, that means there is no `X` which satisfies the above constraints. If the solver returns `0` (which is the value of the constant objective function), that means there is atleast one `X` which satisfies the constraints.

You can use `cvxpy` library for this. Here is a nice [tutorial](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/linear_program.html). Also `cvxpy` library goes well with `numpy`.

And I don't think solving **equations** would work in this case as a tetrahedron is basically composed of four linear inequalities. So you have to solve **inequalities** in order to find a solution in their intersection region.

Comment: Thank you for your help it was very useful. The test block I created to verify the operation of my function gave a positive result, however there were two special cases that I still need to verify that did not go as expected.
1) when the two tetrahedra have a common face
2) when the two tetrahedra have a vertex in common
I want to see if playing with cvxpy I can also solve this problem or I have to do a separate check for these cases.

Comment: Nice! The special cases are also very interesting. I am curious, does the error occur because of floating point calculations?

Comment: No, simply since I am studying a case of interpenetration between two tetrahedra, I have assumed that the touch between these two objects returns to me a false value. Since the convex optimization problem checks for the existence of common points between the two tetrahedra, then touch is also a solution for my optimization problem, but not for my intersection calculation function. Now the goal is to verify if I can distinguish the case of touch from the case of intersection.